# not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object at DetailFrame.Navigate(type)

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

MainPage contains a Splitview and Frame as below xaml.

```
<Frame x:Name="AppShellFrame" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1"
                   Navigating="AppShellFrame_Navigating" 
                   Navigated="AppShellFrame_Navigated">

                    <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <NavigationThemeTransition>
                                <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>

                                    <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo/>

                                </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                            </NavigationThemeTransition>
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </Frame.ContentTransitions>
                </Frame>
```

When I click a item of listview in Splitview then called this Frame

```
public Frame AppFrame => AppShellFrame;

AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(MasterPage), item.Argument);
```

In MasterPage

```
var viewType = e.Parameter as Type;
if (viewType != null && MasterFrame.CurrentSourcePageType != viewType && viewType.Name!="Detail")
{
    MasterFrame.Navigate(viewType);
}

if(viewType.Name=="Detail" && MasterFrame.CurrentSourcePageType!=typeof(Detail))
{
    DetailFrame.Navigate(viewType);
}
```

I called homepage from Splitview then MasterFrame display homepage. That's fine
But I click a item of listview in homepage in MasterFrame then call Detail but show error up.

> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at DetailFrame.Navigate

(viewType).
in homepage behind code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Navigate to MasterPage and call a Detail Page.
/// </summary>

Frame AppFrame = new Frame();
public void ItemClick(Status item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        DetailsVM.StatusId = item.StatusID;
        AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(MasterPage), typeof(Detail));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I fixed that errors:

> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

This is code:

```
public static MasterPage CurrentPage;

public MasterPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DetailFrame.Navigating += DetailFrame_Navigating;
    DetailFrame.Loaded += DetailFrame_Loaded;
    CurrentPage = this;

}

public void NavigateToContentPage(Type type)
{
    DetailFrame.Navigate(type);
}
```

But I get an error:

> -not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object at DetailFrame.Navigate(type)

Comment: I think your DetailsFrame is null. Please put the break point and check it have value or not?

Comment: Then please check inside of Navigate method anything is null

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Please upload a minimal reproduced project.